# AWS S3 Object Lifecycle Exclution

Tags: amazon-s3, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I'm working in Terraform, and am creating an S3 object/folder-with-content.  I would like to exclude that object from my lifecycle policy.  But I'm not sure to exclude the object (folder-object/sample) from the lifecycle policy (Terraform Code Below):

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket" "s3_test" {
  bucket = "test-bucket-upload"
  acl    = "private"
  key    = "folder-object/sample"

  tags {
    Name        = "test-bucket"
    Environment = "lab"
  }

  server_side_encryption_configuration {
    rule {
      apply_server_side_encryption_by_default {
        sse_algorithm = "AES256"
      }
    }
  }
  lifecycle_rule {
    id                  = "glacier-transfer"
    enabled             = true

    transition {
      days              = 360
      storage_class     = "GLACIER"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of excluding, use prefix to identify the objects your lifecycle rule should apply to. For example, the rule below would only apply to objects in the new_objects folder in your bucket:

```
...

lifecycle_rule {
  id                  = "glacier-transfer"
  enabled             = true
  prefix              = "new_objects/"
  transition {
    days              = 360
    storage_class     = "GLACIER"
  }
}

...
```

Comment: And if I wanted a lifecycle policy only for the buckets root folder, but wanted to exclude "new_objects/" is there a way to do that?

By the way this is great.  Your comment already puts me on the right track.

Comment: You could  use tags instead of prefix. Tag every new object (e.g new_object=true) added that you want to be part of the lifecycle policy.

tags {
      "new_objects"  = "true"
}